# react-native-twitter-lite: Error: Unable to resolve module 'crypto'

Tags: react-native

I have followed the instructions to install react-native-twitter-lite via [npm page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-twitter-lite) ....as per below:

```
npm install twitter-lite
```

....then on app.js:

```
import Twitter from 'twitter-lite';

const twtClient = new Twitter({
  consumer_key: 'xxxx',
  consumer_secret: 'xxxx',
});
```

...I get error `Unable to resolve module crypto from node_modules\twitter-lite\dist\twitter.js: crypto could not be found within the project`
...even though I can see that the file `node_modules\twitter-lite\dist\twitter.js` exists

Comment: what node version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be that cryptojs is missing from your dependencies (not installed in your app), but react-native-twitter-lite still need it to run for security. You surely have the twitter.js but not the crypto.js. Cryptojs is used by twitter-lite to cypher and encrypt data. You may choose to use Nodejs's crypto module or react-native's build-in cryptojs. I always choose the later one for a more native behavior. For that, simple run

> npm install react-native-crypto-js --save.

The first time I run into this issue [this source](https://giters.com/draftbit/twitter-lite/issues/110) helped me understand.

Comment: Unfortunately Im still getting same error after installing react-native-crypto-js.
What is the npm command for Nodejs's crypto module?  Maybe Ill try that

Comment: I think the issue is the react native version. To make it work with React Native 0.63, you probably will need to downgrade crypto-js version to 3.3 . As for the other option, the node crypto module is already bundled in nodejs, so no need to install it and only useful when you want to create your own custom function to cypher and encrypt. But this is not the case so react native cryptojs is the best fit. Can you check the react native version of the app? Are you using Expo? With react-native cryptojs you are on the right track.

Comment: The version of react-native-crypto-js is 6.9.0.
When I try to downgrade to 3.3.0.....npm tells me the package does not exist.

Comment: When it says "package does not exist" I don't know whether it's the first install which is still missing, or the older 3.3 version that is not available for installation. If it is the latest version that is not installed then good, the right way to install the 3.3 version is npm install crypto-js@3.3.0 --save. But if it is the older version that isn't available, then you need to uninstall the latest version first and then reinstall the specific version 3.3 which is a stable one I used.

Comment: Because twitter-lite uses the core node modules crypto I recommand installing [rn-nodeify](https://github.com/tradle/rn-nodeify) to map react-native with core modules. Also see [this](https://github.com/brix/crypto-js/issues/303)

Comment: I uninstalled react-native-crypto-js....then ran react-native-crypto-js@3.3.0.  Same error saying package does not exist.
Installed rn-nodeify as well but unfortuantely this didnt help either

Comment: Maybe the package was renamed? Maybe you could contact the developer.

Answer (score 0):

This happens to me, most likely when installing a new package to my project, I didn't try to install `react-native-twitter-lite` , but my general approach is :

- Try to install the missing module yourself , in your case, install Crypto
- Delete `node_modules` and install the dependencies again, run `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`
- run your project `npm start` and then `npm run android && npm run ios`

Comment: I tried [npm install react-native-crypto-js --save] then [rn -rf node_modules] then [npm install].....still getting same error.
Interestingly it builds fine in Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

If you install native module you will need to rebuild your app. It’s jut hot reloadable.

If that’s not your issue, but you’re using typescript, you may be missing a dependency that can fortunately be resolved using:

npx typesync

Are you using Expo or Xcode/Android Studio? If Expo, note that Expo handles a Bare and a Managed workflow. If you are using a managed workflow you may have these issues since Expo is managing native modules for you so you may want to check if Expo has a similar dependency to what you’re using, otherwise you may want to eject from Expo.

If developing for iOS, you may also want to check if you’ve installed the pods you need. You can do this using the following:

npx pod-install from root of project directory (likely same directory as package.json)

All else fails:
rn -rf node_modules
npm install && npx pod-install
(If usingTypescript also try npx typesync)

If developing for Android, make sure you add necessary code on gradle file, can be pasted anywhere (likely in docs)

Comment: Im not using Expo.....Im building using Android Studio (havent tried building app on IOS yet).
Which necessary code on gradle file are you referring to?

I tried [npm install react-native-crypto-js --save] then [rn -rf node_modules] then [npm install].....still getting same error.
Interestingly it builds fine in Android Studio

Comment: Sometimes you just need to copy and paste like a line or two of code into something like a .gradle file, I’ve done this a handful of times when using native modules. Usually this code will be included in the docs. I do believe you’ve linked docs you’re using but I have yet to check it myself.